# Does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'getenumerator'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am fetching data from WEB API. Be at the time of display is shows me error.

```
public class PricingTooltemPrice
{
    // Other Propery
    public List<CoinDateList> CoinDateList { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CoinDateList
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

My action method:

```
public ActionResult ItemPrice(string itemName, string itemId)
{
    var Data = GetPrice(itemName, itemId);
    return View("MyViewPage", Data);
}

public PricingTooltemPrice GetPrice(string itemName, string itemId)
{
    PricingTooltemPrice model = new PricingTooltemPrice();
    var client = new RestClient();
    client = new RestClient("GET DATA FROM API");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("x-user-id", this.UserId);
    request.AddHeader("x-api-token", this.token);
    request.AddHeader("x-api-key", this.apikey);
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PricingTooltemPrice>(response.Content);
    return model;
}
```

My View Page Code:

```
@using helloworld.Models
@model helloworld.Models.PricingTooltemPrice
```

Here I am facing the issue while fetching the data using for each loop.

```
@foreach (var data in Model.CoinEntry)
{
               
}
```

When I type **Model.CoinEntry**, it shows me an error:

> **CoinEntry** does not contain a public instance or extension definition
> for **GetEnumerator**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model contains `CoinDateList` property, but not  `CoinEntry`:

```
@foreach (var data in Model.CoinDateList)
{
   ... 
}
```